# Bitwise - How can I check if a binary number contains another?

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-manipulation

```
  A  = 110000000    -    384 Blue+Red
  B  = 011000010    -    194 Green+Black+Red

  A & B =   C  = 010000000    -    128 Red
```

How can I check if B contains all the bits in A and perhaps others? In the case above I would like to get "false".

I'm using XCode & objective-c but that shouldn't matter as far as I know

Comment: It's unclear what the colors are refering to in your example. I guess your question is "How can I check if all the bits set to 1 in number A are also set to 1 in number B ?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

B contains A if A & B (ie, the intersection) is equal to A:

```
(a & b) == a
```

Which is analogous to

```
a ⊆ b ↔ (a ∩ b) = a
```

from set theory.

Comment: a ⊆ b ↔ (a ∩ b) = a Took me back a few years, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean exactly the same bits, the test is `A == B`.

If you mean `B` must have all the bits that are set in `A`, and perhaps others, `(A & B) == A`.

Comment: Of course your test won't print anything: your value of `B` doesn't contain all the bits of your value of `A`, so you get `false` as you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use ex-nor

```
 In C ^ is ex-or operator and ~ is complement, to get ex-nor use ~(a^b)
```

if a and b are same then all bits will be 1 in ~(a^b)

Comment: Or, equivalently, `a == b`. I don't think the obfuscation adds anything.

Comment: Definitely. To perform bit wise operator you can use above.