# bit pattern Check

Tags: c#, bit

I have a pretty rookie question for you guys.

I want to write a bit check.
There I want to write a Boolean check if a two bit pattern is identical.

Unfortunately I did not understand the bit check completely.

```
    public bool BitPatternCheck(int number, int operand)
    {
        if (operand >> number != 0)
        {
            false;
        }

    }
```

Now in the Main method i  would like to pass 2 numbers and check if all bits in operand are also present in number.

Comment: Could you explain what you want that function to do exactly? Is this question answered by [Checking if a bit is set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2431732/555045)? Or by [How can I check if a binary number contains another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21257165/555045) (C++ but the answers work in C#)

Comment: Asking if the "Bit pattern is identical" is the same as asking "are the numbers the same?" 
  You'd simply use the `==` operator. That is different from asking "if all bits in operand are also present in number", for which you would use the `&` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bitwise and:

`(number & operand) == operand`

This is called masking. It will bitwise and each bit in `number` with the corresponding bit in `operand`. If they are both `1` then the resulting number will have the bit set in that position. For example:

```
number:  001110111
operand: 001100011
result:  001100011
```